# Do you know a way to remove a 7-spline lug nuts?

Tags: lug-nut

I lost the key, and I cant find a store that sell this item.
I tried to use Gator Grip but the tool is not that deep to remove the lug nuts.
Here is the photo:
[image]

Comment: Something like this? - https://www.amazon.com/Circuit-Performance-Black-Point-Spline/dp/B01LXD3KE6

Comment: no that is different. that one is triangular. mine has rectangular splines

Comment: It may still fit even though they are triangular.

Comment: Or this one - https://www.amazon.com/Dynofit-Spline-Lugnuts-Replacement-Warranty/dp/B07GV7J767/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=7+Point+Star+Spline+Lug+nut&qid=1567424432&s=gateway&sr=8-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grind or cut slots in the ends and use a bar to remove.

Then purchase a new set of lugnuts with two keys and put one in a safety deposit box or somewhere else safe so you don’t loose it...

I have managed to remove a damaged lugnut in the past by taking an "old" socket and smacking it over the damaged nut... a 3lb hammer is the perfect tool, BUT don't miss and hit the rim... unscrews fine, but don't expect the socket to fit its stated size any more...

Comment: Perhaps a nut splitter would work too?

Comment: @Martin and how would you get a nut splitter in to that confined area?

Comment: I like the brute force approach!

Answer (score 0):

A search for "Locking Lug Nut Removal Tools" on Amazon shows a variety of sets for about $70. Individual sockets are available for under $20. These sockets are designed to cut into and grip the lug nut allowing it to be removed. The advantage to a set over an individual socket is that if it slips you can move down a socket size and start again. You could ask a local tire shop what they would charge to remove them for you. It might not be much more than the cost of the tool. You also have to add in the cost of new lug nuts.